# Columns mixup in BigQuery is a bug or a feature?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How is this:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 
    'a' AS col_a,
    'b' AS col_b
)

SELECT 
  col_a -- missing comma passes validation
  col_b
FROM t
```

Results into this:

```
╔═══════╗
║ col_b ║
╠═══════╣
║ a     ║
╚═══════╝
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug, your main query means

```sql
SELECT col_a AS col_b FROM t;
```

**col_a** comes from table `t` and **col_b** is it's alias.

Comment: Phew... this logic is not ambiguous at all...

Comment: I was confused at first look, too. took a minute to realize it. ;)